# Difference in ViewController pushing

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller

I'm doing the CS193P Stanford course tutorials and also some Apple iOS dev tutorials, and there's a difference between how they push the ViewController to the screen

Apple does this:

```
 UINavigationController *aNavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:rootViewController];

    self.navigationController = aNavigationController;
```

Stanford suggests doing this:

```
navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] init];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:rootViewController animated:NO];
```

How are they different?

PS: btw, Apple's method work and the Stanford one doesn't display anything and I don't know why.

Comment: For the second method, you must still create an instance of `UINavigationController`. It isn't there by default.

Comment: @PengOne yes, I just realized that and corrected it, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that using the pushViewController:animated method you are going to add the controller at the top of the stack of the controllers ([push a new view controller on the stack](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html)).

In the second method you are not initializing the navigationController.

Comment: I just saw why it wasn't working, I was forgetting to alloc and init the navigationController at the beginning of the method, so I was pushing to an inexistent object. They are 2 ways of doing the same thing i will update the code for future reference